# Qt：Inaccurate time interval of qtimer

Tags: c++, qt

I want to display time on mainWindow, and 10 seconds passes in reality,  1 hour passes in the program.

mainWindow.cpp

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
ui.setupUi(this);

myTimer = new QTimer(this);
connect(ui.toolButton_2, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(start_stimulation()));
connect(myTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(dealTimeOut()));
...
}

void MainWindow::start_stimulation()
{
    qDebug() << ma.currentTime.toString("MM-dd HH:mm") << endl;
    if (myTimer->isActive() == false)
    {
        myTimer->start(100);
    }
}


void MainWindow::dealTimeOut()
{
    QString str = ma.currentTime.toString("MM-dd HH:mm");
    //update time
    ma.currentTime = ma.currentTime.addSecs(36 * ma.move_speed);
    ui.timedisplay1->setText(str);
    ui.timedisplay2->setText(str);

    
}
```

But it seems that when it passes 10 seconds in reality, the time in the program only passes 10 minutes or so.

I am really confused.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please edit your question to provide a [mcve] and clarify what you're trying to achieve.  In the code shown you never set any timeout value.

Comment: first you might need to set the single short property to true in your case

Comment: what do you mean exactly with this ***"and 10 seconds passes in reality, 1 hour passes in the program."*** can you paraphrase that please

Comment: If I understand correctly, your `ma.move_speed` should be set to 1 and the `ma.currentTime` will pass 1 hour after 100 times timeout of the timer. (For each timeout, 36 secs will be added. So total is 100 * 36 secs == 60 mins == 1 hour)